# where can I download the latest build of ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu

Is it still on the beta stage?I'm asking because I downloaded it before ,some time in december. And I just want to make sure that I download the latest one. I don't want to be downloading the same thing. So I ask where I can download the latest build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can download [Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid Lynx) Daily Build](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/). it updates daily.

Answer (score 1):

It should keep itself updated to the latest build through the repository update process.